# Immediate form input highlighting

Tags: javascript, highlighting

I'd like to know a simple way to instantanely higlight an array of words while i write in a input form/textbox.

Answer (score 0):

Highlighting moves the cursor to the beginning of the textbox (at least in IE) and typing replaces highlighted text with the newly typed text. Even if you figured out how to keep moving the cursor to the place the user wants to type, I imagine there would be a lot of annoying blinking as the text highlighted and unhighlighted. What are you trying to accomplish? Could you add `onblur="this.select()"` instead?